# Dibenzoyl-L-tartaric acid won't show up on HPLC chromatogram

Tags: analytical-chemistry, chromatography

I'm trying to develop a method for HPLC to detect dibenzoyl-L-tartaric acid. Concentration doesn't matter at this point; I'm only concerned with detection. The problem I'm having is the compound won't show up at any wavelength I've tried. I think I have the appropriate column (one specifically designed for organic acids). The run time is more than enough, the sample is essentially saturated and my injection volume is 25 mL.

The compound seems like it would have a chromophore, so I've been trying wavelengths between 210 and 270, but nothing works. Literature also turns up nothing.

Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackExchange! Take a look at the [help] center to learn how to use the site.

Comment: Are you sure it's coming off the column at all? (Try and TLC) the waste stream. Carboxylic acids (especially multiple in one molecule) can be quite difficult to move on a HPLC column— adding some modifier to keep them proton ated often helps (0.1% TFA or similar).

Comment: What are you using as the mobile phase?

Comment: Is this normal or reversed phase? I'd also guess that the injection volume is not 25 mL. Maybe 25 uL or 2.5 uL?

Comment: Test the method with something else, for example, benzoic acid.  If that doesn't show up either, there is a problem with your system.  What's the column packing, back pressure, flow rate and mobile phase?